# some apps are not in settings app on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, settings

I noticed that the apps I developed and tested on my device, doesn't appear in the Settings. Actually a lot of apps are missing there. Why is that?

This image depicts what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every app needs separate settings. In order to have settings in the app developer would need to implement separate *Settings.bundle* in the app.
More about *Settings.bundle* on the [Apple Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).